# How to rotate svg paths suitable for both svg and canvas. I want to apply for all shapes that are calculated based on paths

Tags: html, canvas, svg

I have rotated my text to 60. The datalabel shape remains the original position. I want it to be the same position as text.
I have attached the sample path which is not rotated .
code:

```
<path id="container_svg"  d="M 796 297.22080291970804 L 875 297.22080291970804 L 875 327.22080291970804 L 796 327.22080291970804 L 796 297.22080291970804Z"></path>

<text id="container_svg_Text0" x="1169" y="5.80859691808597" fill="black" font-size="15px" font-family="Segoe UI" font-style="Normal" font-weight="lighter" opacity="1" text-anchor="start" transform="rotate(198,1169,0.8085969180859692)" labelrotation="198">eleven</text>
```

Comment: we really need rather more than this. Where's the code that does the rotation and where's the text?

Comment: Hi Robert ,                                                                                          I have set the transform attribute for text.I want to perform the same level rotation to the path <text id="container_svg_Text0" x="1169" y="5.80859691808597" fill="black" font-size="15px" font-family="Segoe UI" font-style="Normal" font-weight="lighter" opacity="1" text-anchor="start" transform="rotate(198,1169,0.8085969180859692)" labelrotation="198">eleven</text>

Comment: So set the same transform. What's the problem?

Comment: How to set transition for path attribute?

Comment: rotate i need to set for path like we do in text.I need to know a simple method without changing the calculation